# Building Error in OSGEphemeris

Tags: c++

I am trying to build OSGEphemeris. I checked out the source code from https://code.google.com/p/osgephemeris/source/checkout
and linked it with OSG 3.2.0. But it is giving compilation error like-

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::string'

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::string'

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'

error C2664: 'osgEphemeris::StarField::_parseStream' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::istream &'

etc.
I have not changed anything in the source code. How can i make it work?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The problem was that osgDB has its own String classbased on std::string and osgText has its own fstream class. Both are defined in headers with the same name as standard library headers. So by removing these headers from the visual studio additional include directories the problem was solved.
Maybe this will be helpful in case someone faces the same problem.